# Why does name lookup in the parameter-declaration-clause of a lambda expression not find init-captures?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example

```
int main() {
    const char* x;
    [x = 1] (decltype(-x) y) {};
}
```

[I tested 3 compilers on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5cnhzTo34) and they all reject this because you can't apply unary minus to a pointer.

I can't figure out why the standard requires this behaviour, though. According to [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#6),

> An *init-capture* inhabits the lambda scope ([basic.scope.lambda]) of the *lambda-expression*. [...]

The lambda scope is defined in [[basic.scope.lambda]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.lambda):

> A *lambda-expression* `E` introduces a *lambda scope* that starts immediately after the *lambda-introducer* of `E` and extends to the end of the *compound-statement* of `E`.

The *lambda-introducer* is the part that's enclosed in square brackets, so it would appear that immediately after the closing square bracket in `[x = 1]`, name lookup for `x` should begin to find the *init-capture* and not the variable `x` declared in the enclosing block scope.

But according to the compilers, while we're still in the *parameter-declaration-clause*, name lookup for `x` doesn't find the *init-capture*. I'm sure they're right and there's something wrong with my reasoning, but what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ draft on eel.is is newer than C++20. In C++23, the code you've written will (probably) be allowed. There is in fact [an example](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#example-3) on eel.is that is very similar to yours (`decltype` of *init-capture* in region before the opening `{`)

```
auto counter = [i=0]() mutable -> decltype(i) {     // OK, returns int
  return i++;
};
```

However, all the compilers *currently* fail to compile this example, just as they fail to compile yours. This is because, in C++20 (or, the closest draft I can find online), the relevant section (draft N4868, [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/6`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda#capture-6)) actually reads (emphasis mine):

> An *init-capture* without ellipsis behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form `auto init-capture ;` whose **declarative region is the *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement***, ...

I.e. the *init-captures* are indeed only in scope for the body, and not for the parameter declarations or return type. So your code is invalid C++20 but will probably be valid C++23.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C++23 feature that was approved as a DR.
It is [implemented by clang](https://godbolt.org/z/7nf635PnM) and should ship in clang 17.

The relevant papers are https://wg21.link/P2036R3 and https://wg21.link/P2579R0